# How to show last 5 post in wordpress using this bootstrap 4?

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I want to dynamically the following code written by Bootstrap 4 using the WordPress loop. I want show the 5 last posts in the following code.

I want to show the post Like as the picture:
[image]

I see another post but I need to customize the design.

```
<?php $posts = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 5));
    ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-md-stretch">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        < !-- Post 5 -->
          <div class="card border-0 shadow-lg mx-2 mx-lg-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', ['class' => 'img-fluid rounded-top mx-auto d-block']);
                                                            ?><div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-text pt-3"><a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();
                                                                                                                    ?></a></h5>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            < !-- Post 2 -->
              <div class="card border-0 shadow-lg mx-2 mx-lg-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', ['class' => 'img-fluid rounded-top mx-auto d-block']);
                                                                ?><div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-text pt-3"><a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();
                                                                                                                        ?></a></h5>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            < !-- Post 1 -->
              <div class="card border-0 shadow-lg mx-2 mx-lg-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', ['class' => 'img-fluid rounded-top mx-auto d-block']);
                                                                ?><div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-text pt-3"><a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();
                                                                                                                        ?></a></h5>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            < !-- Post 4 -->
              <div class="card border-0 shadow-lg mx-2 mx-lg-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', ['class' => 'img-fluid rounded-top mx-auto d-block']);
                                                                ?><div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-text pt-3"><a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();
                                                                                                                        ?></a></h5>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            < !-- Post 3 -->
              <div class="card border-0 shadow-lg mx-2 mx-lg-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', ['class' => 'img-fluid rounded-top mx-auto d-block']);
                                                                ?><div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-text pt-3"><a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();
                                                                                                                        ?></a></h5>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```